# High Level Tennis Leagues Europe

Tags: tennis

I am a high school senior looking to take a gap year before I head to college and play D1 tennis. I am looking for top level tennis leagues that I can play in for that year abroad. I am aware of the Bundesliga in Germany, the Bundesliga in Austria, and the Spanish Absoluto championships in Spain. Are there leagues in Italy and Switzerland? I would love to play in one of these places.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the league in Switzerland is also known to be of high quality due to the preferable geographic location of Switzerland. Since Italy, Germany and France are quite close, players from these countries participate. The league there is called *Interclub*: https://www.swisstennis.ch/national/rado-interclub

Similarly, France has a team competition called *Interclub*. See more information here: https://www.fft.fr/competition/tennis/epreuves-par-equipes/interclubs-seniors-pro-pro-b

The top league in Italy is called *Serie A1*: https://www.federtennis.it/Campionati-tornei-e-classifiche/Campionati-nazionali/campionati-affiliati